# Generate unique bigint surrogate keys in HIVE table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to build surrogate keys (bigint data type) in HIVE table for my 10M data. I am trying to use either `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL2)` OR `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1)`. Now as Hadoop is a distributed architecture and runs in parallel in multiple nodes, so will we have duplicate keys in this case? Means can we have key=10 for COL1='First Value' (generated from one work node) and same value for key like key=10 for for COL1='Second Value' (generated from another work node). If yes, then is there any other way to handle to generate unique BIGINT type of keys? If it will generate unique keys, then process wise how it is being handled while working with multiple nodes? Is there any co-ordination across the nodes to take care of the situation and make sure the keys are unique? We tried with sample 10K records and found keys are unique.

Comment: I think you wlll have duplicates unless to use `OVER (ORDER BY COL1, COL2)` which probably gives bad peformances. However COL1 + ROW_NUMBER() gives you a unique key. Can't you use it?  10K records is too small

Comment: And if your table is already partionned by COL1, you should keep it in the surrogate key otherwise a query on the key would scan all partitions

Comment: Table is partitioned on COL3, which is a DATE column